# Search deleted users/groups in AD with python-ldap

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

If you delete an user or group in windows AD, it will in "DElETE objects".
I want to use python ldap lib to get them.
Code:

```
<code>
import ldap
uri = "ldap://10.64.74.17"
user = "XXXXXXXXXX"
password = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 5)
ldap.protocol_version = 3
ldapClient = ldap.initialize(uri)
ldapClient.simple_bind_s(user, password)
filter = "(&(objectclass=person)(isDeleted=true)(!(objectclass=computer)))"
results = ldapClient.search_s("DC=xx,DC=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,filter)
for result in results:
  print result
ldapClient.unbind_s()
</code>
```

It can't show deleted objects.
What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an [ldap control](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap-controls.html#ldap.controls.LDAPControl) to your search : create the request control for the particular operation, and then pass a collection of controls to your search request as an optional parameter.

In your case, this OID for AD is [1.2.840.113556.1.4.417](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/3c5e87db-4728-4f29-b164-01dd7d7391ea).

> **LDAP_SERVER_SHOW_DELETED_OID : 1.2.840.113556.1.4.417**
>
> Used with an LDAP operation to specify that tombstones and deleted-objects are visible to the operation.

```
tombstone_control = ('1.2.840.113556.1.4.417',criticality=1)
results = ldapClient.search_s("DC=xx,DC=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,filter, [tombstone_control])
```

You can also scope your search base to `CN=Deleted Objects, DC=xx,DC=com` as this is where all deleted objects end up. You should make sure your deleted objects are there first. You can use `ldp.exe` to check.